# Redirect Query_string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do the redirect, but it is not working.

I want to redirect:

```
http://www.example.com/page/168?s
```

To:

```
http://www.example.com/page/168
```

Using

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=s$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```

In case of somebody to need

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need QSA (Query string append):

```
Using RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=s$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1? [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Otherwise the the rewrite does not include the part after the questionmark.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  
Didn't work.  
The log doesn't show any error but it doesn't redirect.
The "s" after the questionmark was not excluded.